# Can I create an image using a WYSIWYG tool and put it in a LaTeX file with good results?

Tags: latex, wysiwyg, photoshop

Computer people:

I am typesetting a math paper using LaTeX.  I need to create come fairly complicated diagrams including circular arcs, triangles, and small text boxes, to include in the document.  I might like to have line segments or arcs of different widths, and maybe shade in some triangles, and include brief text snippets inside and outside the shaded regions.  I would like to create the image using a WYSIWYG tool.  I will probably need to convert it to .eps or .pdf format, since I think these are the only image formats LaTeX people use (please correct me if I am wrong).  I have access to Adobe Photoshop, which I have never used before but which my family members can help me with.

Before I set about doing this, can anyone tell me if this is a good plan?  For example, if I create an image in Photoshop, can I convert it to a decent-looking .eps or .pdf image?  In an earlier paper, I created a geometric image using PSTricks.  The result looked excellent, but it took hours and hours of painstaking work.  I'd rather use a WYSIWYG tool if possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Latex can handle .jpg or other image files as well. You just have to declare it in the preamble.

```
\DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.jpg}
```

I would say the higher the quality of your input diagram the better it looks later on in your final document. This means if you create your original diagramm with a low resolution you will get a result with a low resolution. Another thing I experienced is that you should avoid to increase the size of your diagramm in latex with `scale`or stuff like this. Hopefully this helps a bit.